# installing R in Ubuntu...issue

Tags: r

I have attempted to install R on my Ubuntu 16.10 Yakkety.

I placed the following deb in my /etc/apt/sources.list file.

```
deb http://cran.ma.imperial.ac.uk/bin/linux/ubuntu yakkety main
universe restricted multiverse
```

However, after running `sudo apt-get update`, I get the following message, which I do not understand:

```
Fetched 102 kB in 6s (15.7 kB/s)                                                                                                                                            
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/george-edison55/cmake-3.x/ubuntu yakkety Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://cran.ma.imperial.ac.uk/bin/linux/ubuntu yakkety Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/george-edison55/precise-backports/ubuntu yakkety Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
```

Has anyone come across this before, when installing R in Ubuntu 16.10?

Answer (score 2):

You forget to import the pgp-key for this repository. Therefore the error reports.

To add the key run `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E084DAB9` afterwards `sudo apt update`.

There is a lengthy explanation of how to add their repositories here: http://cran.ma.imperial.ac.uk/bin/linux/ubuntu/README

Answer (score 2):

The line in your `sources.list` file should be:

```
deb https://cran.ma.imperial.ac.uk/bin/linux/ubuntu yakkety/
```

You do not need "main" or so.

And then, read the instructions for **Secure APT** on https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/. `apt` complains about not being able to authenticate the packages from the server.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you install directly using

`sudo apt-get install r-base`

Or download the deb from [here](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/yakkety/universe/base/r-base)

and install using gdebi

Comment: The Ubuntu repository does have R (as well as many, many packages like r-cran-spatial), but they are often not the newest versions.